# How do I remove non-existant printers from my system print dialogue?

Tags: xubuntu, printing, gtk

Due to flaky support from Canon, it took me several tries to get my printer installed.  For every failed attempt, however, I now have an entry to a printer in my gtk system print dialogue.  Only one works, and you have to guess which one.  How do I remove entries from the system print dialogue?  I am running CUPS 2.3.1 on XUbuntu 20.04.

Comment: Point a browser at the CUPS web interface: `http://localhost:631`.

Comment: That page shows only the one printer that is actually connected, not the six additional that appear in the print dialogue.

Comment: Click on the "Printers" tab. Click on a "bad" printer. In one of the pulldown lists you can delete the printer.

Comment: The Printers tab shows only the good printers.  The bad printers show up only in the system print dialogue.

Comment: Six additional entries in the dialog seems rather excessive when the CUPS web interface shows only a single installed queue. Stop CUPS, `systemctl stop cups`, and say whether any entries disappear or remain in the GTK dialog.

Comment: Knowing the printer model and whether it is USB/wireless connected is always useful.

Comment: Stopping CUPS removes the excess entries.  Restarting them puts them back in.  The printer is a Canon MF244dw, and it is connected via USB.

Comment: Does stopping cups-browsed produce the same outcome as with stopping CUPS? Please give the output of `lpstat -t`.